# Java Doubly Circular Linked List Deletion

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have created a doubly circular linked list and wanted to delete a node with a given value.If we assume that there's a circular doubly linked list with node values 11,12,13,14 where 11 is the head node.Then to delete node with value 11, we need to set previous pointer of 12 to point to 14 and next pointer of node 14 must be set to 12 and 12 is then made the head node.So, now if we choose to display the list answer should be 12,13,14 but unexpectedly answer comes out to be 12,13,14,11.And when I add the line no. 19(Delete function mentioned below) to the code,expected output is displayed.Hence,**I wanted to know if the logic is correct and we have changed all the previous and next pointer values,then why the output differs.If I want to to delete the first node i.e the head node then why we should set the next value to be null(as in line no. 19(Delete function mentioned below)?**

NODE STRUCTURE:

```
public class Node{
int data;
Node next,prev;   //next and previous pointers for a node
}
```

DELETE FUNCTION

```
1     public void del(int x)
2    {
3       Node n=head;
4      do{
5          if(n.data==x){break;}
6           n=n.next;
7       }
8     while(n.data!=x);
9       if(n.data==x && n!=head)  //for deleting any other node except first node
10       {
11         n.next.prev=n.prev;
12         n.prev.next=n.next;
13       }
14       else if(n.data==x && n==head)  //for first node deletion
15       {
16           head.next.prev=head.prev;
17           head.prev.next=head.next;
18           head=head.next;
19        // n.next=null;
20       }
21       else{System.out.println("Element not found");}
22    }
```

**P.S: I also tried to print nodes along with next value where even after changing the next pointer of node 14 from 11 to 12(i.e deletion of 11),still node.next was printing 11 as next of node 14.Why?**
Code for display function given below:

```
public void display()
    {
        Node n=head;
       
        if (head != null)
    {  
        do
        {
            System.out.println(n.data+" and its next is "+n.next.data);
            n=n.next;
        }while(n!=head);
        System.out.println("");
    }
        else{System.out.println("Please add an entry to the linked list");}
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code for add?

Comment: *FYI 1:* The code will run forever if `x` is not found. --- *FYI 1b:* Code is unreachable: `else{System.out.println("Element not found");}` --- *FYI 2:* Code will throw `NullPointerException` if the list is empty. --- *FYI 3:* `do{ if(n.data==x){break;} n=n.next; } while(n.data!=x);` is better written as `while (n.data != x) { n = n.next; }`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep it as simple as possible, hope it helps. (its hard to read your code so I just made it from scratch)

```java
public class DoublyLinkedList {
    // no null state
    DoublyLinkedList prev = this, next = this;
    int value;

    public DoublyLinkedList(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // add node to the back of the list
    public void add(int value) {
        DoublyLinkedList node = new DoublyLinkedList(value);
        node.next = this;
        node.prev = this.prev;
        this.prev.next = node;
        this.prev = node;
    }

    // remove the node
    public void remove() {
        prev.next = next;
        next.prev = prev;
    }

    // find the node with given value
    public DoublyLinkedList find(int value) {
        DoublyLinkedList 
            end = this.prev,
            current = this;
        while(current != null) {
            if(current.value == value) return current;
            if(current == end) break; // to prevent infinite cycle
            current = current.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    // dump the list
    public void dump() {

        DoublyLinkedList 
            end = this.prev,
            current = this;
        while(current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.value + " ");
            if (current == end) break;
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // testing
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);

        list.dump();

        list.find(3).remove();

        list.dump();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not the same as niya, he/she made 2 classes, first, node, the other is the List that saves the head. and the problem is hapening when deleting the head